# Why does it come out variable not set?

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have a problem, when I try to debug this coding it will appear

> RUNTIME ERROR 91; OBJECT VARIABLE OR WITH BLOCK VARIABLE NOT SET

and it also will highlight at this line

`Range("L8").Value = Cells(2, FindMe.Column)`.

May I know what is the error?

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A
'
    Set Searchme = Range("L9")
    Set FindMe = Range("A2:G126").Find(What:="Searchme", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Range("L8").Value = Cells(2, FindMe.Column)

    Range("A1:G126").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
        "L8:L9"), CopyToRange:=Range("N8:T8"), Unique:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Probably the value that you're trying to find doesn't exist in the range A2:G126.

Comment: You could try to use `debug.print(FindMe)` in between the `Set FindMe` and `Range("L8")..` lines to see the value of `FindMe`.

Comment: @Luuklag sorry, i cant get the idea. can you show it to me?

Comment: @ImranMalek i already put data in the range A2:G126.

Comment: @Ayra Are you able to find those values manually with Ctrl+F ?

Comment: @ImranMalek yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value that you're trying to find doesn't exist in the range.

Try to wrap your code around If condition to check if find returns anything or not !

```
Sub test()
    Set Searchme = Range("L9")
    Set FindMe = Range("A2:G126").Find(What:="Searchme", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)



If FindMe Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No value found."
    'or you can negate the condition like "If Not" if you want to continue and remove the else part.
Else
  Range("L8").Value = Cells(2, FindMe.Column)
  Range("A1:G126").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
        "L8:L9"), CopyToRange:=Range("N8:T8"), Unique:=False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, but still have the same error even I'm using your coding.

Comment: You are still trying to assign the value of FindMe to cell L8. Propper indentation from OP would have helped here. I've gone about and edited that in your code.

Comment: @ayra, I corrected a mistake in the code, try again.

Comment: @Luuklag Thanks for the edit , I completely missed that ! :)

Comment: @Luuklag thankyou. it works. but, can I ask -- why it said no value found even though I already have data? did you have any idea about this?

Comment: Your data is probably not a good match, but impossible to say without seeing the data.

Comment: Oh okay, ill try to figure out by myself. Thanks ya! @Luuklag